# Is there a way to link stripe payouts to corresponding invoices included in the payout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Trying to find a way to link a Stripe Connect Payout object to the charges that are included in the payout. Any help on this is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link the charges to a Payout, you can utilize [Stripe's Balance Transactions API](https://stripe.com/docs/expand/use-cases#charges-in-payout) which tracks historical changes to your Stripe account balance.

Here is an example using Node.js:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('your_secret_key');

const balanceTransactions = await stripe.balanceTransactions.list({
  payout: 'payout_id',
  type: 'charge',
  expand: ['data.source'],
});

const charges = balanceTransactions.data.map((txn) => txn.source);
```

This code returns a list of charges tied to that specific payout. Note that this works for automatic payouts. For manual payouts, you have to track transaction history yourself.

For Connect with destination charges, you must expand through source_transfer and source_transaction properties.

Answer (score 0):

@os4m37 answer is good and the right way to achieve my requirement. I am posting below my solution in Ruby.

```
require 'stripe'

Stripe.api_key = 'your_secret_key'

# The ID of the connected account you want to interact with
connected_account_id = 'your_connect_account_id'
payout_id = 'stripe_payout_id'

charges = Stripe::BalanceTransaction.list({payout: payout_id, limit: 100,
                                                 expand: ['data.source.invoice'], type: 'charge'},
                                                {stripe_account: connected_account_id})
```

The charges array will have all the balance transactions that is linked to the **payout_id**. The **charges[:data]** object will have all the souce transactions and the invoice objects related to the payout.